# alert box not working properly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<script>
    function fun(){
          let i=document.getElementById("input")
          if(i==="sam")
            {
               alert("welcome SAM")
            }
          else
            {
               alert("welcome user")
            }
        }
      </script>
     
        <input id="input"/>
        <button onclick="fun()">click</click>
```

if user type input as 'sam' it should be follow the if block but every time it execute else part .how to change the condition that when user type 'sam' in textbox then only it follow if block or else execute else part

Comment: you mean `i.value`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure your input is correct.
2. Instead of writing "if(i===sam)", write "if(i=="sam").
3. Other than that, I think there's a problem with your input method. Javascript doesn't directly get the input from the box. For further information, check this link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-take-user-input-using-HTML-forms
4. If you want to do it the easier way, just put "document.getElementById("input").value"

Answer (score 2):

`getElementById` method returns html element, if you want to get text inside input you should use `document.getElementById("input")?.value`

Comment: '?' sign is used if there are no inputs with id `input`

Answer (score 1):

Just add **.value** ahead of **document.getElementById("input")**

Just like that:

```
let i=document.getElementById("input").value
```

Basically, you're not passing the text to the variable **i** that is the reason **else** is executing